# Position of text within the block element

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I need to make sure that if the text line is too long, it does not go above the price, but goes to a second line as soon as it approached the block with the price. I hope this makes sense. Please refer to the line 'Green tea with a tiny piece of lemon'. The word 'of' should not go above the line, it should have moved to the second line.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```css
.lst {
  font-family: montserrat;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul.lst li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.lst li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #252525;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f3f2e8;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul.lst li em {
  font-style: normal;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  color: orange;
}

ul.lst li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: #BFD3EE;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul.lst li:hover span {
  background: #658BBB;
}

ul.lst li:hover a{
  color: #61304B;
}

ul.lst li:hover em{
  color: #61304B;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lst">
  <li><a href="#">Americano<em>$2.24</em></a><span style="width:20%">20%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green tea with a tiny piece of lemon<em>$22.50</em></a><span style="width: 50%">50%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Black Tea<em>$2</em></a><span style="width: 75%">75%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Black coffee<em>$2</em></a><span style="width: 90%">90%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Latte<em>$2</em></a><span style="width: 50%">100%</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a structure of your HTML a little bit and change your `<a>` to flexbox i.e. from `display: block` to `display: flex`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.lst {
  font-family: montserrat;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul.lst li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.lst li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #252525;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f3f2e8;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul.lst li a .text {
  flex: 1;
}

ul.lst li em {
  font-style: normal;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  color: orange;
}

ul.lst li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: #BFD3EE;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul.lst li:hover span {
  background: #658BBB;
}

ul.lst li:hover a{
  color: #61304B;
}

ul.lst li:hover em{
  color: #61304B;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lst">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="text">Americano</div>
      <em>$2.24</em>
    </a>
    <span style="width:20%">20%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="text">Green tea with a tiny piece of lemon</div>
      <em>$22.50</em>
    </a>
    <span style="width: 50%">50%</span></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="text">Black Tea</div>
      <em>$2</em>
    </a>
    <span style="width: 75%">75%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="text">Black coffee</div>
      <em>$2</em>
    </a>
    <span style="width: 90%">90%</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="text">Latte</div>
      <em>$2</em>
    </a>
    <span style="width: 50%">100%</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're the best! Thanks so much! @sauravrastogi

Comment: Its my pleasure @Ira

Answer (score 2):

You can set `display: flex` on `a` and that should fix the problem.

```css
.lst {
  font-family: montserrat;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul.lst li {
  position: relative;
}
ul.lst li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #252525;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f3f2e8;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul.lst li em {
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 25%;
  color: orange;
}
ul.lst li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: #BFD3EE;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
ul.lst li:hover span {
  background: #658BBB;
}
ul.lst li:hover a {
  color: #61304B;
}
ul.lst li:hover em {
  color: #61304B;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lst">
  <li><a href="#">Americano<em>$2.24</em></a><span style="width:20%">20%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green tea with a tiny piece of lemon<em>$22.50</em></a><span style="width: 50%">50%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Black Tea<em>$2</em></a><span style="width: 75%">75%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Black coffee<em>$2</em></a><span style="width: 90%">90%</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Latte<em>$2</em></a><span style="width: 50%">100%</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the price with absolute position and some padding for the link text so it doesn't go on the price? something like this:

```
ul.lst li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #252525;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f3f2e8;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

ul.lst li em {
    font-style: normal;
    float: right;
    color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Not to fight your solution, but I'd say it's a bad sign when you have to use absolute positions for a problem like this.

Comment: Honestly, I think its about where and how you wanna use that part (price in this case), but I agree with your opinion, thanks for letting me know what you think.